# HERE API KML modificacion style

Tags: api, map

estoy intentando realizar un mapa con kml pero una intención es que cuando seleccione una parte del mapa ese kml su estilo se modifique y aparezca el kml con la modificación que se hizo pero no logro hacer que se visualice el cambio del estilo del kml en el mapa estoy utilizando el codigo de prueba de here

```js
reader.parse();

var layer = reader.getLayer();
map.addLayer(layer);

layer.getProvider().addEventListener('tap', function(ev) {
var placemark = ev.target.getData().kmlNode;
var style = placemark.querySelector("Style");
console.log(placemark);

var lineStyle = style.querySelector("LineStyle");
if (lineStyle) {
style.removeChild(lineStyle);
}
console.log(placemark);

var polyStyle = style.querySelector("PolyStyle");
if (polyStyle) {
polyStyle.querySelector("fill").textContent = "0";
}
map.removeLayer(layer);

var updatedLayer = reader.getLayer();
map.addLayer(updatedLayer);

});
```

estoy esperando seleccionar partes del mapa y que el kml me de diferentes estilos cuando esto ocurre